# ExtJS can't set value on a row

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am adding a row to a store as follows:

```
var store = this.getStore();
var newrow = store.add(Sytem.model.Info.Settings.create({ID: id, MINVAL: 1});
```

However when I try to set a value in the newly added row:

```
newrow.set('MAXVAL', 1000);
```

I get an error message `newrow.set() is not a function`

As far as I can tell from the documentation this is the correct way to set a value on a newly created row of a store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`store.add()` returns an `Array` of the records created.  You should be able to use `newrow[0].set('MAXVAL', 1000)`.

BTW, you may find it easier to add your record like this:

```
store.add({ID: id, MINVAL: 1});
```

See the docs for more: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-add

Comment: Thanks, never realized it was an array for some reason. We use create for some custom logic I believe, which is why that is there.

Comment: @Wige API is your friend